# Let $R$ be a ring with unity such that $a^2=a~\forall~a\in R.$ Let $I$ be a prime ideal in $R.$ Then $|R/I|=2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Let $R$ be a ring with unity such that $a^2=a~\forall~a\in R.$ Let $I$ be a prime ideal in $R.$ Then $|R/I|=2.$

$a^2=a\implies a(a-1)=0\in I\implies a\in I~or~a-1\in I\implies a+I=0+I~or~a+I=1+I$

Also since $I$ is a proper ideal of $R$ we have $I\ne1+I$

So, $|R/I|=2$

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, sir. Right on.

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, $R/I$ is an integral domain with $a^2 = a$ for all elements. In an integral domain, the only idempotents are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2):

*Community wiki answer to remove the question from the Unanswered queue:*

Yes, your proof is correct.